# Jquery tab not working in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Hello all,

I used jquery tabs in my website which is working proper in all other browsers except IE.

Please resolve this issue. Thanks in Advance

I used this script :

```
jQuery(function() {</p>
/* Tabs */
    jQuery("#productsList").tabs();</p>
});
```

Comment: see this link it might be a help - https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-tabs-not-working-in-ie8-and-ie9

Answer (score 0):

Things worked in IE6, Firefox, and IE8 running in IE7 compatibility mode; but not in 'normal' IE8. My solution was to put this code in the header

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```